# How do you do MongoDB $Sum Grouping with a field that you have created in project?

Tags: mongodb

Here is a basic MongoDB query which I followed a template for that groups together the unique dates in date field and counts them.

```
db.Tweets.aggregate ( [
{ $group: { _id: "$date" , Number_Of_Tweets_Sent : { $sum : 1 } } }
] )
```

[image: MongoDB Group Count]

Next I have a piece of code that I created which creates a new field called convert. The convert field categorizes data from Tweet field into 'contains word' or 'does not contain word'

```
db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0, tweet: 1,convert:{$cond: { if: 
{
   $or: [
      { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /Tesla/i } },
             { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /rocket/ } },
             { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: "coffee" } }
   ]
}

, then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}}])
```

[image: contains words categorization MongoDB]

Next I would like to merge the code together so I have a group aggregation result like the first screenshot.

{"_id" : "contains words","Number_Of_Tweets_Sent: 193}
{"_id" : "does not contain words","Number_Of_Tweets_Sent: 7895}

I have checked comments and tried:

db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0, tweet: 1,convert:{$cond: { if: { $or: [ { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /Tesla/i } }, { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /rocket/ } },{ $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: "coffee" } }]} , then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}},{ $group: { _id: "convert" , Number_Of_Tweets : { $sum : 1 } } }])

and also run it without the tweet column in project

db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0,convert:{$cond: { if: { $or: [ { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /Tesla/i } }, { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /rocket/ } },{ $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: "coffee" } }]} , then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}},{ $group: { _id: "convert" , Number_Of_Tweets : { $sum : 1 } } }])

The fault seems to be that it is not accepting the $group on the convert field I created, or the position/syntax of the code below which I inserted after the other code before ])

**,{ $group: { _id: "convert" , Number_Of_Tweets : { $sum : 1 } } }**

Comment: on project you forgot to add number    `_id: 0, tweet: ,`   use something like [this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) or [this](https://mongoplayground.net/) to help you with json syntax mistakes.

Comment: Looks like the `$` is missing from `_id: "$convert"`

Comment: Joe I tried adding $ still not luck

Comment: I am now saving the result of the query to a new collection called 'test' to see if I can query that db.test.save(db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 1, tweet: 1,convert:{$cond: { if:
{
$or: [
{ $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /Tesla/i } },
{ $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /rocket/ } },
{ $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: "coffee" } }
]
}
, then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}}]))